# How to solve the Nov. 29 cryptoquote in the Wisconsin State Journal?

Tags: cipher

<sub>apparently the [cryptogram](/questions/tagged/cryptogram) tag is a tag synonym for [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) so I guess that's what I'm using</sub>

So recently I have been trying to get back into solving the cryptoquotes because I used to enjoy doing them. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izaCT.png) is the cryptoquote for today in the Wisconsin State Journal, which I'm struggling to solve:

```
GAED CXH'L YGDUD QAP'UD
TUAE; CL'X YGDUD QAP TCHS
NCMGL YGDH KNN MUAYX
SKUR. - VCDUFD OUAYH
```

Here's my attempt at solving this:

Right away I assumed `CXH'L`=`ISN'T`, meaning that we can rewrite this with

```
     ISN'T
GAED CXH'L YGDUD QAP'UD

      IT'S            I
TUAE; CL'X YGDUD QAP TCHS

 I  T              S
NCMGL YGDH KNN MUAYX

        I
SKUR - VCDUFD OUAYH
```

Now I felt like it would be reasonable to assume that `QAP'UD`=`YOU'RE`, mainly since `you're` is the only word that I could think of that had two letters after an apostrophe, so now it is

```
 O E ISN'T   E E YOU'RE
GAED CXH'L YGDUD QAP'UD

 RO   IT'S   ERE YOU  I
TUAE; CL'X YGDUD QAP TCHS

 I  T   EN      RO S
NCMGL YGDH KNN MUAYX

  R     IER E  RO
SKUR - VCDUFD OUAYH
```

Now I can make out the first name `PIERCE` (`V`=`P` and `F`=`C`) and this is my current progress and where I'm stuck:

```
 O E ISN'T   E E YOU'RE
GAED CXH'L YGDUD QAP'UD

 RO   IT'S   ERE YOU  I
TUAE; CL'X YGDUD QAP TCHS

 I  T   EN      RO S
NCMGL YGDH KNN MUAYX

  R    PIERCE  RO
SKUR - VCDUFD OUAYH
```

So my question is: Is there anything I could do from here, or have I assumed anything incorrectly so that I'll now have to restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There are two very likely options for the word `..ERE` and either one will give you the plain letter for cipher `G`.

Comment: You should also be writing out the substitution key as you solve it, so you can keep track of which plain letters are not yet assigned a cipher letter.

Comment: oh okay, but there's only one good one, right? I guess "there" is possible, but I feel like "where" would be better because we have then `HO.E ISN'T WHERE YOU'RE` which I feel like would make more sense. Edit: Don't we still have a problem with `KNN` then? That's the only word that uses `K` or `N`.

Comment: You already assumed cipher `H`, but it looks like you missed a few places where it appears.

Comment: Cipher `K` and cipher `N` each appear in two words.